# Image looks saturated in blender sequence editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

never mind I fixed it. it happens to be that I saved in wrong color space.

[image: image in krita]

[image: what's showing in blender]

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the color management here:

[image]